# Using Spring @ModelAttribute with a @RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-validator

I'm building a REST API that uses a @PathParameter for a parent PK and a @RequestBody for the child form parameters. Next I need to validate the @RequestBody values against regex values stored in a database using the param key from the @RequestBody and the parent pk from the @PathParameter, however I've been unable to figure out a good way to add the @PathParameter pk id to the @RequestBody child object before @Valid is called without using @ModelAttribute.

Using @ModelAttribute, I've been able to add the @PathParameter to the @RequestBody object and then validate the @RequestBody object using @Valid. However I found while using @ModelAttribute, Spring no longer throws the MethodArgumentNotValidException therefore eliminating the ability to use a global exception handler.

I found adding BindingResult to the controller handler followed by throwing a new MethodArgumentNotValidException when errors exist the global exception handler could be triggered.

It's my understanding the ModelAttribute is for Spring MVC and not so much  RestController since I'm not using the view, I'm wondering if this is a correct approach or whether there's a better solution. Here's a sample of my code.

**HTTP Post**

```
localhost:8072/api/clover/graph_run/2

[
    {
        "graphKey" : "DATA_DIRECTORY",
        "graphValue" : "/data/clover-prod"
    },
    {

        "graphKey" : "DATAOUT_DIR",
        "graphValue" : "/data/clover-prod/94l"
    },
    {
        "graphKey" : "DELAY_MS",
        "graphValue" : "0"
    }
]
```

**RestController**

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/clover")
public class GraphRunController {

    final CloverServerService cloverServerService;

    @PostMapping("/graph_run/{graphId}")
    public String graphRun(@ModelAttribute("graphId") @Valid GraphJobDTO graphJobDTO,
                           BindingResult  bindingResult ) throws MethodArgumentNotValidException {
        log.debug("GraphRun {}", graphJobDTO);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            throw new MethodArgumentNotValidException(null, bindingResult);
        }

        return cloverServerService.runGraph(graphJobDTO);
    }

}
```

**ModelAttribute in ControllerAdvise**

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ControllerAdvice(  assignableTypes = {GraphRunController.class})
public class GraphRunControllerAdvise {

    final GraphJobRepository graphJobRepository;

    @ModelAttribute("graphId")
    public GraphJobDTO addGraphId(@PathVariable(value = "graphId") Long graphId,
                                  @RequestBody List<GraphJobPropertyDTO> graphProperties) {
        log.debug("ModelAttribute graphId {}", graphId);

        //Query database for the graph job and all it's parameters
        GraphJob graphJob = graphJobRepository.findById(graphId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new HRINotFoundException("No such job execution."
                + graphId));

        GraphJobDTO graphJobDTO = new GraphJobDTO();
        graphJobDTO.setGraph(graphJob.getGraph());
        graphJobDTO.setGraphProperties(graphProperties);

        //Create a map from the database with the key being the GraphKey contained in both the request and the database
        Map<String, GraphJobProperty> jobMap = graphJob.getJobProperties().stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(s -> s.getGraphKey().toUpperCase(), Function.identity()));

        graphProperties.forEach(v -> {
            String graphKey = v.getGraphKey();

            //If the graphKey in the request cannot be found in the database, throw an exception. We will handle the exception
            //in th exception handler
            if(!jobMap.containsKey(graphKey)) {
                throw new HRINotFoundException(String.format("%s is an invalid job parameter.", v.getGraphKey()));
            }

            //Within the database record is the validation message as well as the regex used to validate the incoming value,
            //we set the message and regex in the GraphPropertyDTO object for cross validation later on in the validator.
            GraphJobProperty jobProperty = jobMap.get(graphKey);
            v.setValidationMessage(jobProperty.getValidationMessage());
            v.setValidationRegex(jobProperty.getValidationRegex());
        });

        //Return the graphJobDTO object for validation
        return graphJobDTO;
    }

}
```

**Constraint Validator**

```
@Slf4j
public class GraphRegexValidator implements ConstraintValidator<GraphRegex, GraphJobPropertyDTO> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(final GraphRegex graphRegex) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final GraphJobPropertyDTO dto, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        String regex = dto.getValidationRegex();
        String value = dto.getGraphValue();

        if(regex != null && value != null && !Pattern.matches(regex, value)) {
            log.debug("isValid {} - {}", false, dto);
            addConstraintViolation(context, getMessage(dto, context));
            return false;
        }
        log.debug("isValid {} - {}", true, dto);
        return true;
    }

    private void addConstraintViolation(ConstraintValidatorContext context, String message) {
        context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message).addPropertyNode("graphKey").addConstraintViolation();
    }

    private String getMessage(GraphJobPropertyDTO dto, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return dto.getValidationMessage() != null ? String.format(dto.getValidationMessage(), dto.getGraphValue()) :
                context.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate();
    }

}
```

**DTOs**

```
@Data
public class GraphJobDTO {

    @NotNull
    Long graphId;
    @NotNull
    String graph;
    @Valid
    List<GraphJobPropertyDTO> graphProperties;

}

@Data
@GraphRegex
public class GraphJobPropertyDTO {

    String graphKey;
    String graphValue;
    String validationMessage;
    String validationRegex;

}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible for you to pass `graphId` as part of request body?

Comment: @ManishBansal I'm actually doing a single query for all my regex expressions and passing them into my GraphPropertiesDTO from within the ModelAttribute. To better answer your question, if I added the graphId to the ResponseBody, I would need to add the id to the json as parent id ensuring all child records are using the same parent id and then I still have a similar problem with the validator not having access to that id. If I add it to the child records, then I have multiple database queries within the validator for the regex and chance the parent id being different.

Comment: @ManishBansal I added a little more code sample to my question.

Comment: @ManishBansal I meant RequestBody not Response Body.